# Configure autocomplete in emacs?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I've installed the `auto-complete` package in emacs from MELPA and I can enable it with `M-x auto-complete-mode`. I'm having some issues with configuration though, I've added the following lines to my `.emacs`

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20140201.2101")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20140201.2101/dict")
(ac-config-default)
```

When I start emacs I get an error

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/user/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, popup

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

`auto-complete` requires `popup` and both are listed as installed if I list packages with `M-x list-packages`. Any suggestions on how I should do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plain config like this should work:

```
(setq package-user-dir "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")
(package-initialize)
```

No need to specifically change `load-path`.

Comment: No need to set `package-user-dir` either. The value you have above is the default one.